C#.Net IBM MQ Multi threaded application Connection Issue with Username and Password
When I connect to IBM MQ QueueManager using multi-threading, it does not connect all of the requests to MQ. Few connect and few fail. If I use thread count as 1 then all the request are connected. When I increase thread count to 2 or 3 then few will success and few will fail.
When I connect without UserId and Password, multithreading is working properly.
public class AML_MQIntegration : IDisposable
{
    #region Decalrations
    MQQueue objMQQueue;
    MQMessage objPutMQMessage;
    MQMessage objReadMQMessage;
    MQQueueManager objMQQueueManager;

    public AML_MQIntegration()
    {
       
                    Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
                    properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
                    properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, Common.FTS_MQ_HostName);
                    properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, Common.QUEUE_CHANNEL);
                    properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, Common.FTS_MQ_Port);

                    properties.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, Common.FTS_MQ_UserId);
                    properties.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, Common.FTS_MQ_Password);

                    properties.Add(MQC.USE_MQCSP_AUTHENTICATION_PROPERTY, true);

                    Common.WriteFTSLog("HOST_NAME_PROPERTY " + Common.FTS_MQ_HostName + Environment.NewLine);
                    Common.WriteFTSLog("CHANNEL_PROPERTY " + Common.QUEUE_CHANNEL + Environment.NewLine);
                    Common.WriteFTSLog("PORT_PROPERTY " + Common.FTS_MQ_Port + Environment.NewLine);
                   
                    objMQQueueManager = new MQQueueManager(Common.QUEUEMANAGER_NAME, properties);                                               
               
    }

    public string PutMessageOnQueue_Inward(string message, string strMessageID)
    {

        //bool isSuccess = true;
        string writeQueueName = Common.WRITE_MESSAGE_QUEUENAME_INWARD;
        try
        {
            objMQQueue = objMQQueueManager.AccessQueue(writeQueueName, MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);

            objPutMQMessage = new MQMessage();

            //UTF-8 character encoding
            objPutMQMessage.CharacterSet = 1208;
            objPutMQMessage.WriteString(message);

            objPutMQMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
            objPutMQMessage.MessageType = MQC.MQMT_DATAGRAM;
            objPutMQMessage.Report = MQC.MQRO_NONE;

            objMQQueue.Put(objPutMQMessage);
            objMQQueueManager.Commit();


            if (objMQQueue.OpenStatus)
            {
                objMQQueue.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //LogMQ("Error while putting message in to MQ ," + ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace, "MQ_Error_");
            Common.WriteFTSLog("Exception for PutMessageOnQueue_Inward strMessageID:" + strMessageID + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
            //isSuccess = false;
            message = null;
        }

        finally
        {
            objMQQueue.Close();
            objMQQueueManager.Disconnect();
        }
        //return isSuccess;

        return message;
    }
    }

    public void ProcessInwardInstCovAMLRequestSendProcess(AMLRequestDetails AmlRequestDetail)
    {
        DAL_InwardAMLProcess objDAL_AMLDetails = new DAL_InwardAMLProcess();
        string Error = string.Empty;

        using (AML_MQIntegration objMQIntegration = new AML_MQIntegration())
        {
            try
            {                   
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AmlRequestDetail.Request))
                {                       
                    string XMLSend = objMQIntegration.PutMessageOnQueue_Inward(AmlRequestDetail.Request, AmlRequestDetail.AmlSRQId.ToString());

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(XMLSend))
                    {
                        if (objDAL_AMLDetails.UpdateAMLScreeningRequestInstCov(AmlRequestDetail.AmlSRQId, "U", ref Error))
                            Common.WriteFTSLog("Successfully Saved Inward AML Request Send status for Inward AML Request Id: " + AmlRequestDetail.AmlSRQId);
                        else
                            Common.WriteFTSLog("Failed Saving Inward AML Request Send status for Inward AML Request Id: " + AmlRequestDetail.AmlSRQId);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Common.WriteFTSLog("Failed during Request Send for Inward AML Request Id: " + AmlRequestDetail.AmlSRQId);
                        objDAL_AMLDetails.UpdateAMLScreeningRequestInstCov(AmlRequestDetail.AmlSRQId, "E", ref Error);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Common.WriteFTSLog("Exception occured during Request Send for Inward AML Request Id: " + AmlRequestDetail.AmlSRQId + " " + ex.Message.ToString() + ex.StackTrace);
                objDAL_AMLDetails.UpdateAMLScreeningRequestInstCov(AmlRequestDetail.AmlSRQId, "E", ref Error);
                Common.handleErrorLogInService(ex);
            }
        }
    }


And what do they fail with? What's the MQ reason code?

What is the question you're asking?

And what does your code have to do with your (non-)question?

Where are you applying the multiple threads? I don't see anything configured in the QueueManager for threading, Is it an instance of this AML_MQIntegration per thread, or attempting to call the PutMessage from multiple threads?

@Morag Hughson MQ reason code is 2009

@Steve Py AML_MQIntegration is a constructor which is using to initialize the MQ connection. PutMessageQueue is calling from multiple threads.

What did the queue manager error log show when you get the 2009?

How fast are these messages being posted to the queue? One thing to check is whether the queue reference returned by AccessQueue (objMQQueue) is Disposable, if so it should be wrapped with a using. Looking at the docs around the 2009 error, one reason given was "The maximum number of channels allowed by the queue manager are open". Your code calls Close on the queue which should cover it  but I'd also double check that conditional code is executing as expected. I'm wary of that check against OpenStatus. Why/how could it not be open?

@PradeepKumar - chances are the library isn't thread-safe. Can you give instructions n how to NuGet the library?

Thank you for telling me you got MQ reason code 2009. Is there anything in the AMQERR01.LOG file to expand upon that? Also, are you sharing connections - the default is that you will be, check the value in your SVRCONN channel's attribute MAXSHCNV - report back on whether there is any effect in setting it to 1 from the 10 it defaults to.
